# Why doesn't Python logic doesn't always evaluate to a bool?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logical-operators

In Python I am very used to using the logical operators `and` and `or` and was under the impression that they'd simply get evaluated with the left and right values and replaced with `True` or `False` at runtime.

I recently discovered that this is not the case. Consider:

```
>>> False or 10
10
```

I see the use case. Here if you have a function that returns a value or `False` on failure the above allows you to have a default fallback value. But with `and`:

```
>>> True and re.match("s", "s")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x19f9098>
```

This puzzles me... It seems that the last operand of an `and` evaluation where both operands evaluate to `True` is always returned which makes sense in that it's the last one to run but I don't see why this is preferable to just having a bool.

Why does python do this?
Is there a use case for this that I'm not seeing?
In situations where you know you want a bool is it a good idea to *convert* these values? eg:

```
>>> bool(True and re.match("s", "s"))
True
```

Comment: Because there are other uses besides boolean logic for the `and` and `or` operators.

Comment: Regarding your last question, I don't think I've *ever* used `bool`, except to check in the interpreter whether some unfamiliar type is truthy or not.

Answer (score -1):

In Python doc's words:

> This is sometimes useful, e.g., if s is a string that should be
>   replaced by a default value

[Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) doc.